# Showing that a set is open/closed

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-verification

$\def\R{\mathbb R}$

> Is the set
>
> $$S=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \R^3 \mid e^{x_1} + x_2^2 <x_3 \} \subset \R^3$$ open or closed?

My attempt:

Let $f:\R^3 \to \R$, $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ =$e^x_1 + x_2^2-x_3$. Then $S=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \R^3 \mid f(x_1,x_2,x_3)<0 \}$. Also $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is continuous in $\R^3$ and the set $S=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \R^3 \mid f(x_1,x_2,x_3)<0\}$ is the inverse image of $(-\infty,0)$,which is open in $\R$ and therefore $S$ is open in $\R^3$.

Am i correct ?

Comment: Do you mean $e^{x_1}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right if you mean by $R = \mathbb{R}$ the real numbers.

Comment: Yes, this has been edited into the OP.